# Looping through and printing each variable of a json file python

Tags: python, json

what i am trying to do is loop through this list of items using

```
with open('items.json', 'r') as itemfile:
    shopitems = json.load(itemfile)
    for items  in shopitems['items']:
        print(items)
        print(items['description'])
```

this code that is written in python and print each variable
 the problem here is it doesn't loop through each item and get there description and i cant figure out how to do it.

```
[
  [
    {
      "itemname": [
        {
          "description": "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "itemname": [
        {
          "description": "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "itemname": [
        {
          "description": "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "itemname": [
        {
          "description": "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @ijustcode What are you asking? You are not clear. Does your piece of code not working? What your desired output vs output you got.

Comment: sorry edited to make more sense

Comment: The json was invalid so i corrected it. Is this the JSON snippet you aretrying to parse?

Comment: yes it is the original json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you are able to get items and its description. Your 1st element of the list is text and other element except first one is dictionary so I check if its dictionary than loop through that dictionary and take the item description.
if your json structure is like this you can extract things like the code below

```
with open('items.json', 'r') as itemfile:
    shopitems = json.load(itemfile)    
    for items in shopitems:
        for item in items:
            if (type(item)) == dict:
                for description in item:
                    print("Item Name :", description)
                    for item in item[description]:
                        print("Description :",item['description'])


[{"itemname":[{


        "description": "test"
    }]},

    [{"itemname":[{


        "description": "test"
    }]}],
    [{"itemname":[{


        "description": "test"
    }]}],


    [{"itemname":[{


        "description": "test"
    }]}]
    ]
```

Comment: Hello your answer worked, however i was wondering if there was a way to do this with a json file?

Comment: yaa! will you please elaborate your json structure. if the format is same as mentioned above than just read json in variable and get your work done.